# How to make a slider for day selecting in Ionic 2?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to make a day slider in my Iionic 2 application, but I don't really how to do it. I've been searching on Google, but I couldn't find anything. The closest thing I could find is [this](https://github.com/Pranay92/ionic-date-slider). However, this doesn't work with Angular 2, and I only need a slider with days (Mon-Sun). 
This is how I want it to look like:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYMH9.png). One should be able to select a day(s).

Why I need it:
My application can make be used to plan a trip, and the user should be able to select which day(s) he is going.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this really simple, something like this would suffice:

```
export class MyPage {
    days: [
        { name: "M", selected: false },
        { name: "T", selected: false },
        { name: "W", selected: false },
        { name: "T", selected: false },
        { name: "F", selected: false },
        { name: "S", selected: false },
        { name: "S", selected: false },
    ]
}
```

And in your view:

```
<span *ngFor="let day of days" (click)="day.selected = !day.selected"
      [ngClass]="{ selected: day.selected }">
    {{ day.name }}
</span>
```